# Highlight individual characters and then refreshing the screen to ONLY those characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript (but I like it so far!) and I have a pretty basic little project I'm working on. One component requires me to select characters and then click a button and refresh the screen with JUST the ones that are highlighted. I got the highlighting functionality working using Jquery but I'm wondering about the refresh component. Whats the best way to approach this?

EDIT: I guess I should provide a few more details. This list of characters could potentially be very long. Like a few hundred or more. Also after somebody clicks and highlights the characters two things need to happen when they click submit. One the database needs to be informed which characters were highlighted and keep a tally (this is the reason I tagged each span with a unique ID), and two the screen needs to refresh with just the highlighted characters shuffled into random order.

So I think what I'm looking for is a way to capture these highlighted characters into a JSON array. Then I can forward the information to the server, process it, and reload the screen with the new (smaller) list shuffled. This process could potentially repeat.

Does that help inform design decisions? I'm not sure how to use java script to capture the highlighted characters.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      span.highlight {background-color: #FFFF00;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").on("click",".letter", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass("highlight");
        });
      });
    </script>    
    </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <span class="letter" id="A">A</span>
    <span class="letter" id="B">B</span>
    <span class="letter" id="C">C</span>
    <span class="letter" id="D">D</span>
    <span class="letter" id="E">E</span>
    <span class="letter" id="F">F</span>
    <span class="letter" id="G">G</span>
    <span class="letter" id="H">H</span>
    <span class="letter" id="I">I</span>
    <span class="letter" id="J">J</span>
    <span class="letter" id="K">K</span>
    <span class="letter" id="L">L</span>
    <span class="letter" id="M">M</span>
    <span class="letter" id="N">N</span>
    <span class="letter" id="O">O</span>
    <span class="letter" id="P">P</span>
    <span class="letter" id="Q">Q</span>
    <span class="letter" id="R">R</span>
    <span class="letter" id="S">S</span>
    <span class="letter" id="T">T</span>
    <span class="letter" id="U">U</span>
    <span class="letter" id="V">V</span>
    <span class="letter" id="W">W</span>
    <span class="letter" id="X">X</span>
    <span class="letter" id="Y">Y</span>
    <span class="letter" id="Z">Z</span>

<input type="button" onclick="Reduce()" value="Remove Non Highlighted Chars">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Something like `$('.letter').hide();$('.highlight').show();`?

Comment: See my Edit, I think I was too vague before but I'm guessing a simple "hide" action is not enough in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to refresh the screen:

```
$( "span.letter:not(.highlight)" ).fadeOut();
```

If you really want need to reload the page, you could put the visible letters in the hash of your url. The hash is the part after `#` and you retrieve it with `window.location.hash`. For an URL like `http://yoururl.com/letters/highlight#abc` it would yield `#abc`. The refresh would then effectively be a redirect to your same URL with a different hash parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I see what you're saying. But if they are in the URL wouldn't that limit the overall length? It seems like it might be better to pass this data back and forth using JSON. At least the server will need to see the JSON. I'm not sure if I need to then pass BACK the same array and refresh the screen with it or if the browser can simply refresh itself somehow and remember the new lists of chars. See my Edit about for a more accurate description of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: To get an array of the selected characters: ``$( "span.letter.highlight" ).text();``

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqDKC/).